# Express error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I use express with typescript and want to import my file without extension but it is not working I got this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\myexpress\dist\config\test' imported from C:\btc-myexpress\dist\server.js
```

Here is some snippets:

tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

nodemon

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": ".js,.ts",
  "ignore": [],
  "exec": "tsc && node dist/server.js"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "start": "npx tsx watch src/server.ts",
    "prettier": "npx prettier --write src/server.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix"
  },
...
```

server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { MyFunc } from './config/test';

const app = express();

const data = MyFunc();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`server started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

MyFunc.ts

```
export const MyFunc = () => {
  return 'test';
};
```

```
folder structure
/dist
/src
 /config
 /routes/
/node_modules
tsconfig.json
nodemon.json
package.json
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong I hope anyone can help me. I have so many files and I dont want now to change every file from 'src/file' to 'src/file.js'